# C++ Arrays and make_unique

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, unique-ptr, raii

As a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding) post I wonder how its implementation of `make_unique` plays with allocating function-temporary buffer arrays such as in the following code.

```
f()
{
  auto buf = new int[n]; // temporary buffer
  // use buf ...
  delete [] buf;
}
```

Can this be replaced with some call to `make_unique` and will the `[]`-version of delete be used then?

Comment: Reading the answers: no, there is no simple answer :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is another solution (in addition to Mike's):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

template <class T, class ...Args>
typename std::enable_if
<
    !std::is_array<T>::value,
    std::unique_ptr<T>
>::type
make_unique(Args&& ...args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if
<
    std::is_array<T>::value,
    std::unique_ptr<T>
>::type
make_unique(std::size_t n)
{
    typedef typename std::remove_extent<T>::type RT;
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new RT[n]);
}

int main()
{
    auto p1 = make_unique<int>(3);
    auto p2 = make_unique<int[]>(3);
}
```

Notes:

1. new T[n] should just default construct n T's.

So make_unique(n) should just default construct n T's.

1. Issues like this contributed to make_unique not being proposed in C++11.  Another issue is:  Do we handle custom deleters?

These are not unanswerable questions.  But they are questions that haven't yet been fully answered.

Comment: ... but these questions have been (partially) answered in C++14, and make_unique is now [richer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

Comment: @einpoklum:  Correct.  Note the date on the Q/A.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working with this code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

namespace Aux {
    template<typename Ty>
    struct MakeUnique {
        template<typename ...Args>
        static std::unique_ptr<Ty> make(Args &&...args) {
            return std::unique_ptr<Ty>(new Ty(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }
    };

    template<typename Ty>
    struct MakeUnique<Ty []> {
        template<typename ...Args>
        static std::unique_ptr<Ty []> make(Args &&...args) {
            return std::unique_ptr<Ty []>(new Ty[sizeof...(args)]{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
        }
    };
}

template<typename Ty, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<Ty> makeUnique(Args &&...args) {
    return Aux::MakeUnique<Ty>::make(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```