# What can std::remove_extent be used for?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm studying new features provided by C++11 and I found [std::remove_extent](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_extent).

```
typedef std::remove_extent<int[24]>::type A; // A is int
```

However I can't find a usage for this, aside from defining a new type from an existing type by removing a dimension from the given type.

Could anyone suggest why C++11 introduced this feature? Is there any benefits of using it?

Comment: Why don't you search for "remove_extent"? On SO, there is e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10150181/) which makes use of `remove_extent`.

Comment: "I can't find a usage for this, aside from..." - what you mention there is the entire point of this, so you've just answered your question. More specifically, the type you're removing extent from could be hidden behind the `typedef`, or more commonly, a template parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a good example of using `std::remove_extent` in the C++ Standard itself.

template function that creates an object of smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`

```
template <class T> unique_ptr<T> make_unique(size_t n);
```

returns the following expression (20.8.1.4 unique_ptr creation p.#4)

```
unique_ptr<T>(new remove_extent_t<T>[n]())
```

Consider for example declaration

```
auto p2 = std::make_unique<int[][10]>(2);
```

In this case make_unique need to remove dimension specified like `[]` in the type declaration `int[][10]` and substitute it for `[2]` getting `int[2][10]` in the new expression.

Answer (score 2):

When you work with arrays, you may need to get the total number of elements the array has including sub-arrays. This can be done with some template meta-programming, by using `std::extent` and `std::rank` along with `std::remove_extent`.

```
template <class T, std::size_t N = std::extent<T>::value >
struct total_elements 
{
    using M_type = typename std::remove_extent<T>::type;
    static constexpr std::size_t value = N * total_elements< M_type >::value;
};

template <class T>
struct total_elements<T, 0> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1> {};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef6634bed23ca532).

This can be particularly useful if you work with `vector` of `vectors` because the storage is not guaranteed to be contiguous: by giving the total number of elements and a 1D `vector`, you will obtain that.  You'll also need some pointer arithmetic to make it behave as if it were multidimensional, but that's easy to abstract in a class.

---

As a note, the standard does not obligate you to use it: if you find a place where it may be useful, then go for it.