# C++ Destructors with Vectors, Pointers,

Tags: c++, destructor

As far as I know, I should destroy in destructors everything I created with `new` and close opened filestreams and other streams.
However, I have some doubts about other objects in C++:

- `std::vector` and `std::string`s: Are they destroyed automatically?
- If I have something like

  ```
  std::vector<myClass*>
  ```

  of pointers to classes. What happens when the vector destructor is called?
  Would it call automatically the destructor of `myClass`? Or only the vector is destroyed but all the Objects it contains are still existant in the memory?
- What happens if I have a pointer to another class inside a class, say:

  ```
  class A {
    ClassB* B;
  }
  ```

  and Class A is destroyed at some point in the code. Will Class B be destroyed too or just the pointer and class B will be still existent somewhere in the memory?

Comment: "Or only the vector is destroyed but all the Objects it contains are still existant in the memory?" - fix your thinking here. The objects contained by a `vector<myClass*>` are `myClass*` objects, that is to say objects of pointer type. They are destroyed when the vector is destroyed, but destroying a pointer does not affect the object that the pointer points to. So the objects that the vector contains are *not* still existent in memory. Imagining that the objects pointed to by the pointers are "contained in the vector" is obstructing you from being able to answer your own question :-)

Comment: Incidentally, you should use the `add comment` links below each answer to respond to them or ask for clarification. Don't use the `Post Your Answer` link!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> std::vector and std::strings: Are they destroyed automatically?

Yes (assuming member variables are not pointers to `std::vector` and `std::string`).

> If I have something like std::vector what happens when the vector destructor is called?
>   Would it call automatically the destructor of myClass? Or only the vector is destroyed but all the Objects it contains are still existant in the memory?

If `vector<MyClass>` then all objects contained in the vector will be destroyed. If `vector<MyClass*>` then all objects must be explicitly `delete`d (assuming the class being destructed owns the objects in the `vector`). A third alternative is `vector` of smart pointers, like `vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>`, in which case the elements of the `vector` do not need to be explictly `delete`d.

> What happens if I have a pointer to another class inside a class

The `B` must be explicitly `delete`d. Again, a smart pointer could be used to handle the destruction of `B`.

Comment: shared_ptr is not provided. should I download something? Boost?

Comment: @ISTB, yes. There is `boost::shared_ptr` and `boost::scoped_ptr`. C++11 added smart pointers `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` (`#include <memory>`).

Comment: By the way, if I am using shared_ptr, how can I use new? I think that shared_ptr<ClassA> a = new ClassA(); will not work

Comment: @ISTB, you `shared_ptr<ClassA> a(new ClassA());` or `shared_ptr<ClassA> a = make_shared<ClassA>();`

Comment: And what happens if later I have a vector<std::shared_ptr<ClassA>> in whicH I push the ClassA objects by using shared_ptr<ClassA> a(new ClassA()); and then I call vector.clear(), will it destroy the ClassA objects created by new and pushed into the vector?

Answer (score 8):

You only need to worry about for the memory you have created dynamically (When you reserve memory with `new`.)

For example:

```
Class Myclass{
   private:
       char* ptr;
   public:
       ~Myclass() {delete[] ptr;};
}
```

Comment: if the class member is pointer and public, is it better "new" and "delete" in the same class ? (Because it's more clearly to read the code)

Answer (score 3):

- if they are in automatic storage, yes. You can have `std::string* s = new std::string`, in which case you have to delete it yourself.
- nothing, you need to manually delete memory you own (for memory allocated with `new`).
- if you allocated `b` with `new`, you should destroy it in the destructor explicitly.

A good rule of thumb is to use a `delete/delete[]` for each `new/new[]` you have in your code.

A better rule of thumb is to use RAII, and use smart pointers instead of raw pointers.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. `std::vector` and `std::string` and `MyClass` all have 1 thing in common - if you declare a variable to be any of those types, then it will be allocated on stack, be local to the current block you're in, and be destructed when that block ends.

E.g.

```
{
    std::vector<std::string> a;
    std::string b;
    MyClass c;
} //at this point, first c will be destroyed, then b, then all strings in a, then a.
```

If you get to pointers, you guessed correctly: Only the memory the pointer itself occupies (usually a 4 byte integer) will be automatically freed upon leaving scope. Nothing happens to the memory pointed to unless you explicitly `delete` it (whether it's in a vector or not). If you have a class that contains pointers to other objects you *may* have to delete them in the destructor (depending on whether or not that class *owns* those objects). Note that in C++11 there are pointer classes (called smart pointers) that let you treat pointers in a similar fashion to 'normal' objects:

Ex:

```
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> a = make_unique<std::string>("Hello World");
    function_that_wants_string_ptr(a.get());
} //here a will call delete on it's internal string ptr and then be destroyed
```

Comment: How can `make_unique("Hello World")` ever result in a `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` (without crazy expression template stuff)? Did you mean `make_unique<std::string>("Hello World")` (assuming a sane `make_unique` function)?

Comment: Sorry, my fault just somehow assumed that would exist. There's a sane implementation that's not crazy though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding

Comment: That still requires you to specify the type to be constructed by `make_unique`.

Comment: Yep, that was an oversight of mine.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have something like std::vector what happens when the vector destructor is called?

It depends.

If you have a vector of **values** `std::vector <MyClass>`, then the destructor of the vector calls the destructor for every instance of `MyClass` in the vector.

If you have a vector of **pointers** `std::vector <MyClass*>`, then you're responsible for deleting the instances of `MyClass`.

> What happens if I have a pointer to another class inside a class

`ClassB` instance would remain in memory. Possible ways to have `ClassA` destructor to make the job for you are to make `B` an instance member or a smart pointer.

Comment: So, practically the only problem is when I use pointers. As long as I use them, I have to destroy everything myself. Except if I am using smart pointers

Comment: @ISTB. You're right. See the answer from Luchian Grigore for a better explanation.

Comment: @ISTB: The problem is when you use raw *owning* pointers to dynamically allocated objects, which you should never be doing, in a vector or otherwise.  Owning pointers should always be smart pointers, but raw pointers can still be used as non-owning reassignable references.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector`, `std::string` and as far as I know all other STL containers have automatic destructors. This is the reason why it is often better to use these containers instead of `new` and `delete` since you will prevent memory leaks.

Your `myClass` destructor will only be called if your vector is a vector of `myClass` objects (`std::vector< myClass >`) instead of a vector of pointers to `myClass` objects (`std::vector< myClass* >`).

In the first case the destructor of `std::vector` will also call the destructor of `myClass` for each of its elements; in the second case the destructor of `std::vector` will call the destructor of `myClass*`, which means it will free the space taken to store each pointer but will not free the space taken to store the `myClass` objects themselves.

The `Class B` objects you point to will not be destroyed, but the space assigned to store its pointer will be freed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. `std::vector` and `std::string`are automatically when they finish out of scope, calling also the destructor of the objects contained (for `std::vector`).
2. As said before, `std::vector`is destroyed when it finish out of scope, calling the destructor of the objects contained. But in fact, in this case, the objects contained are the pointers, not the object pointed by the pointers. So you have to `delete` them manually.
3. The same as (2). A will be destroyed and so the pointer, but not the class B pointed. You have to provide a destructor for A that `delete` B.

In C++11 there is a very useful solution: use `std::unique_pointer`. Can be use only to point a single object and this will be deleted when the pointer goes out of scope (for example when you destroy your `std::vector`).

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr