# Custom STL deleter for any type of resource

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I checked many links about custom cleaners like [C++ Destructors with Vectors, Pointers,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068950/c-destructors-with-vectors-pointers) but still didn't find the answer.
For the ones interested in solutions jump to Update 1/2 on the bottom of question. Solutions 1/2 where found during discussion, thanks to active and attentive participants.
I want to make a custom automatic deleter for **something**. Let's look at following sample

```cpp
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
....
int HeigthMapFromImg(const wchar_t* imgPath, std::vector<std::vector<float>>& heights)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    int x = HeightMapFromImgApi(imgPath, heights);

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return x;
}
```

Note, [std::unique_ptr, deleters and the Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841396/stdunique-ptr-deleters-and-the-win32-api) is not an answer. The question is not about writing own wrappers and not about WinAPI.  [One-liner for RAII on non pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611215/one-liner-for-raii-on-non-pointer) is a similar question but the answers are overengineered.
In the sample the GDI+ token is used to call GdiplusShutdown when work finished. I want to automate it with **unique_ptr** and I'm trying something like this

```cpp
int HeigthMapFromImg(const wchar_t* imgPath, std::vector<std::vector<float>>& heights)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    std::unique_ptr<ULONG_PTR, decltype(Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown) > ptr(gdiplusToken, Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown);
    int x = HeightMapFromImgApi(imgPath, heights);

    return x;
}
```

But no matter that I do it doesn't compile, the code is written in VisualStudio

```
1>...BitmapReader.cpp(145): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<ULONG_PTR,void (ULONG_PTR)>' being compiled
1>...BitmapReader.cpp(145,109): error C2660: 'std::unique_ptr<ULONG_PTR,void (ULONG_PTR)>::unique_ptr': function does not take 2 arguments
1>...\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\memory(2686,5): message : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<ULONG_PTR,void (ULONG_PTR)>::unique_ptr'
```

The STL pointer wrappers works very well with anything that looks like a pointer but the GDI+ token is defined as ULONG_PTR which is defined as __int64. I would expect it to be a PTR but it is not. When I use pointers is no problem, for instance a buffer of wchar_t:

```cpp
std::wostream& ShowLastError(std::wostream& os)
{
    auto localdeleterw = [](wchar_t* a) {::LocalFree(a); };
    wchar_t* pBuffer = 0;
    int ret = ::FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, GetLastError(), 0, (LPWSTR)&pBuffer, 0, 0);
    if (!(ret && pBuffer))
    {
        os << L"failed to read error";
        return os;
    }
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t, decltype(localdeleterw)> ptr (pBuffer, localdeleterw);
    os << pBuffer << std::flush;
    return os;
}
```

To anticipate writing wrappers, I already written my own which is much cleaner:

```cpp
template<class T, auto deleter> struct cleaner
{
    T resource;
    ~cleaner() { deleter (resource); }
};
```

It works pretty well, but I still have the feeling that it can be done without my own wrappers/workarounds:

```cpp
int HeigthMapFromImg(const wchar_t* imgPath, std::vector<std::vector<float>>& heights)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    cleaner<ULONG_PTR, Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown>  c{ gdiplusToken };
    int x = HeightMapFromImgApi(imgPath, heights);

    return x;
}
```

Answers:
Update 1:
As pointed by apple_apple (thanks), a pointer is required, so I transformed it to a pointer by passing **&gdiplusToken** instead of **gdiplusToken**, then indirecting it in the cleaner function, it works, but still looks like a workaround:

```cpp
auto dtr = [](ULONG_PTR* a) {Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(*a); };
std::unique_ptr<ULONG_PTR, decltype(dtr) > ptr(&gdiplusToken, dtr);
```

Update 2:
As experimental solution, the suggestion from  Igor Tandetnik (thanks) is also an option, but looks like not being part of VisualStudio
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit
Update 3:
Answers suggesting writing a wrapper, please read attentive the question. I already have my own, see section about the class **cleaner**. Anyway, I highlight it once again:

```cpp
template<class T, auto deleter> struct cleaner
{
    T resource;
    ~cleaner() { deleter (resource); }
};
///// and using
...
{
....
    cleaner<ULONG_PTR, Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown>  c{ gdiplusToken };
```

Comment: I think the problem is `std::unique_ptr<ULONG_PTR>` actually store a pointer to `ULONG_PTR`, so the deletor not match up (which should looks like `void(ULONG_PTR*)`)?

Comment: @appleapple I tried to cast it to a pointer. It still refuses to compile, with different error.

Comment: well you cannot blindly cast a `ULONG_PTR` to pointer, it's not safe at all

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T, Deleter>` would want to pass `T*` to deleter. But `GdiplusShutdown` does not take a pointer type. You could cast `ULONG_PTR` to some pointer type on the way into `std::unique_ptr`, but `std::unique_ptr` won't cast it back when calling the deleter. You could write your own deleter that takes a pointer, casts it and passes it along to `GdiplusShutdown`, I suppose.

Comment: But at that point you would be much better off with a proper scope guard class, like [`std::experimental::scope_exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit) or [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365013/what-is-scopeguard-in-c)

Comment: @appleapple Transforming it to pointer works, just by taking the address of variable and dereferencing it later, please see Update 1

Comment: @armagedescu well yes it work that way. what I mean is you should not `reinterpret_cast` it

Comment: @IgorTandetnik good point about experimental. Reading it now, hope it will be adopted as standard class in the future

Comment: @armagedescu (continue my previous comment) but then it's not a valid pointer once `gdiplusToken` go out of scope. use it like scopedgaurd would not be a problem, but it shouldn't be treat as `unique_ptr` in many way.

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::experimental`, I actually wrote an implementation of `unique_resource` compatible with C++11 as an independent header-only library-- and it sounds like it might solve your problem. It's available free under Boost license on [github](https://github.com/bitwizeshift/scope) (Shameless self-endorsement)

Comment: @Human-Compiler I already have my own. I want one which is available in standard C++ which can be used with writing clean code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that is not a valid duplicate, the core problem here is `ULONG_PTR` is **not** a pointer type. In that question (and **all** it's answer) treat  `HANDLE` as a pointer type (which probably is).

Comment: @RemyLebeau The question looks similar. But the answers are very unclean, old styled, cumbersome and overenginered. My question already contains two much cleaner answers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau do you mean [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842047/5980430)? it clearly state *This works because `HANDLE` **is a pointer** and therefore satisfies NullablePointer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments:

---

ScopeGuard (as suggested by @IgorTandetnik) and probably what @OP ask

- [What is ScopeGuard in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31365013/what-is-scopeguard-in-c)
- [C++11 scope exit guard, a good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669833/c11-scope-exit-guard-a-good-idea)
- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670448/5980430

---

Actual Smart Pointer (as suggested by @RemyLebeau)

- [std::unique_ptr, deleters and the Win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841396/stdunique-ptr-deleters-and-the-win32-api)
  (which only work for pointer type (despite it compiles, see below answer for detail))
- [One-liner for RAII on non pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611215/one-liner-for-raii-on-non-pointer)

---

The solution from @OP (which is ScopeGuard)

```cpp
template<typename T, auto deleter> struct cleaner
{
   T resource;
   ~cleaner() { deleter(resource); }
};

/// and using
{
    cleaner<ULONG_PTR, Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown>  c{ gdiplusToken };
    // do something here
}
```