# Why does C++11 have `make_shared` but not `make_unique`

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make_unique and perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding)

Why does C++11 have a `make_shared` template, but not a `make_unique` template?

This makes code very inconsistent.

```
auto x = make_shared<string>("abc");
auto y = unique_ptr<string>(new string("abc"));
```

Comment: Probably because `unique` needs to construct an object and they thought it's better done explicit

Comment: It's not the code that's inconsistent, it's the library.

Comment: The copy constructor for unique_ptr is private. So make_unique doesn't work without "return value optimization". My guess is according to the language spec this optimization is not mandatory.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to Herb Sutter in [this article](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/) it was "partly an oversight". The article contains a nice implementation, and makes a strong case for using it:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&& ...args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}
```

**Update**: The original update [has been updated](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/) and the emphasis has changed.

Comment: @hyde thanks. I updated it, but the new version does not have the sample implementation included in this answer (it can be found in the comments).

Comment: and `make_unique` will also be available in C++14 in the same `memory` header http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: N3656, adopted into C++14, has a standalone implementation: http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3656.txt