# C++ return type for function producing polymorphic object?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, polymorphism, virtual-functions

As I understand it, to pass/return polymorphic objects you need to use a pointer or reference type to prevent slicing problems. However, to return objects from functions you cannot create on stack and return reference because the local object won't exist anymore. If you create on the heap and return reference/pointer- the caller has to manage the memory- not good.

With the above in mind, how would I write a function which returns a polymorphic type? What return mechanism/type would I use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would return a smart pointer that takes care of the memory management and makes the ownership clear:

```
#include <memory>

struct IFoo
{
  virtual ~IFoo() {}
};
struct Foo1 : IFoo {};
struct Foo2 : IFoo {};

std::unique_ptr<IFoo> make_foo()
{ 
  return std::unique_ptr<IFoo>{new Foo1()}; 
}
```

Note that C++14 has `std::make_unique`, which allows you to do the above without having to call `new` directly. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580432/why-does-c11-have-make-shared-but-not-make-unique).

Comment: and IFoo would be the base type?

Comment: @user997112 yes, correct. I will add some more code to make that clear.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Doesn't the relevant `unique_ptr` constructor being explicit make that illegal? G++ 4.8 and clang 3.2.1 don't like it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah damn, I thought *in return statements only* initialiser lists could call explicit constructors. Pity. After all, we’re not using `return new Foo1;` here, we’re using parentheses so it’s safe.