# Using std::make_unique with a custom deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In using `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter I desire to use `std::make_unique` rather than a raw new.  I am using VC++2013.  It appears to me that there is no way to use `std::unique_ptr` if you are using a custom deleter.  Did I miss something or is this really the case?

---

Additional Information:

I am using a `std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, custom_deleter>` to hold a Windows HANDLE for an opened COM port.

I could write a custom RAII class for this, and it wouldn't be terribly difficult, but I was seeing how hard/difficult/bad it would be to use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a deficit in `make_unique`.

Comment: What is the use case?  If you're using `std::make_unique`, it allocates using `new`, so the default deleter (which uses `delete`) is the correct matched deleter.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The whole point of `make_unique` is to encapsulate the notion of "use `new` to create a `T` *from given constructor arguments* and use `delete` to destroy it".

If you wanted a custom deleter, you would also have to specify how to *create* the object, and then there would be nothing more gained from having the emplacing maker function.

I wrote some examples of custom maker functions for certain unique resource handles [in this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h).

Comment: Theoretically it would be possible to specify a "creator" as well as a deleter, and then you'd have the benefit of the exception safety.

Comment: @LucDanton: Yes and no. `allocate_shared` only uses a user-defined *allocator*, not a *deleter*. That's significantly less powerful a concept. For example, you can't wrap an `std::FILE*` in that. In other words, `allocate_shared` does not expose the full power of `std::shared_ptr`, it only lets you customize the memory allocator.

Comment: Ugh!  They way they've defined make_unique is next to useless, in my opinion.  What does it really gain us over just using the unique_ptr constructor?  What I would really like is a make_unique variant that accepts a deleter as an argument so that it's type can be _deduced_.  That would let me create unique_ptrs with unutterable types for the deleter.  For example: `auto p = std::make_unique<Foo>(x, y, z, [] (Foo* obj) { FancyFreeFunction(obj); });`

Comment: That's a good point.  I guess it gets us into the whole `allocate_unique` debate.  In my off-the-cuff example above, the only way would be operator new.

Comment: @PeterRuderman: allocation and deletion are somehow separate things. Think of `fopen`/`fclose`. You could have an `allocator_deleter` if you just want an ordinary unique-pointer with memory obtained from an allocator, but that would only address part of the problem domain.

Comment: There is a pretty general case that would benefit from a make_unique with a deleter, which is dealing with incomplete types inside unique_ptrs, where you have a deleter that actually only calls delete, but its operator() is defined in a TU that has the complete type.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to wrap c style memory management into a `std::unique_ptr` using a custom deleter that calls a custom free function. This has a make function helper similar to `std::make_unique` [LIVE](http://cpp.sh/6ipa6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

// Some C style code that has some custom free function ptr...
extern "C" {

struct ABC { };

enum free_type_e {
    FREE_ALL,
    FREE_SOME
};

typedef void (free_f)(enum free_type_e free_type, void *ptr);
struct some_c_ops { free_f* free_op; };

void MY_free(enum free_type_e free_type, void *ptr)
{
    printf("%s:%d ptr=%ld\n", __func__, __LINE__, (long)ptr);
    (void)free_type;
    free(ptr);
}

}; // extern "C"

template<typename T>
using c_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T,std::function<void(T*)>>;

template <typename T>
c_unique_ptr<T> make_c_unique(some_c_ops* op, free_type_e free_type)
{
    return c_unique_ptr<T>(static_cast<T*>(calloc(1, sizeof(T))),
                           std::bind(op->free_op, free_type, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void foo(c_unique_ptr<ABC> ptr)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << ":" << __LINE__
        << " ptr=" << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(ptr.get()) <<     std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    some_c_ops ops = { MY_free };
    c_unique_ptr<ABC> ptr = make_c_unique<ABC>(&ops, FREE_ALL);
    std::cout << __func__ << ":" << __LINE__
        << " ptr=" << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(ptr.get()) << std::endl;

    foo(std::move(ptr));

    std::cout << __func__ << ":" << __LINE__
        << " ptr=" << reinterpret_cast<size_t>(ptr.get()) << std::endl;
}
```

Possible output:

> ```
> main:48 ptr=50511440
> foo:40 ptr=50511440
> MY_free:20 ptr=50511440
> main:53 ptr=0
> ```

Comment: I like the custom alias - definitely makes things easier. After that, I create my `unique_ptr` custom pointer wrappers like so - defining: `class MyClass { private: c_unique_ptr<ExternalType> my_wrapper; }`, then initing: `my_wrapper = { externalCreatorFunc(args), [](auto p) { externalReleaserFunc(p); } };`

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know there is no `make_unique` function in the C++11 standard. See

- [Why does C++11 have `make_shared` but not `make_unique`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580432/why-does-c11-have-make-shared-but-not-make-unique)
- [make_unique and perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding)

So I would assume that the `make_unique` is an implementation from Microsoft that is at least not included in the standard.

But nevertheless you can use a custom deleter with `unique_ptr`. When using `unique_ptr` you have to specify the type of the deleter as a second template argument and then pass an appropriate object to the constructor.

Comment: C++14 will add std::make_unique.  Unfortunately there is no way to specify the delete in std::make_unique, so it can only return a unique pointer with the default delete.