# How to use a custom deleter using WinAPI with std::make_unique?

Tags: c++, winapi, stl, smart-pointers

So I'm just experimenting with smart pointers and how I can manage Win32 `HANDLE` objects with them, so I wanted to test out this simple code I wrote.

It's supposed to provide a custom deleter for `std::unique_ptr` to use when the smart pointer goes outta scope.

```
template <typename Function>
class PtrDeleter
{
    Function _Closer;
public:
    void operator()(void* memBlock) const
    {
        _Closer(memBlock);
    }
};

//The std::make_unique is the one causing the problem...
std::unique_ptr<void*, PtrDeleter<decltype(CloseHandle)>> ptr = std::make_unique<void*>(OpenThread(...));
```

The reason I'm using a template for the `Function` parameter is because I'll be using other functions with `CloseHandle`, like `CoTaskMemFree`.

> cannot convert from std::unique_ptr<void *,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'std::unique_ptr<void *,PtrDeleter<BOOL (HANDLE)>>

This is what the compiler is outputting. Why is it still trying to use `std::default_delete` with `std::make_unique`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using std::make\_unique with a custom deleter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788066/using-stdmake-unique-with-a-custom-deleter)

Comment: The [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) implements that already. Have a look at the [RAII resource wrappers](https://github.com/Microsoft/wil/wiki/RAII-resource-wrappers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make_unique` returns `unique_ptr` with defaulted deleter.

To provide your custom version you have to call `unique_ptr(Pointer,Deleter)` version of `unique_ptr` ctor:

```
template <typename Function>
class PtrDeleter {
    Function _Closer;
public:
    void operator()(void* memBlock) const {
        _Closer(memBlock);
    }
};

int main() {
    PtrDeleter<decltype(&CloseHandle)> deleter;
    void* openThread = OpenThread(0,false,0);
    std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(deleter)> ptr(openThread,deleter);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h7KT3K)

Comment: `make_unique` also allocates the object on the heap, which is not what we want here. That function is not at all suitable here. It also doesn't have any performance benefits like `make_shared` has compare to naked `new`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::make_unique` cannot make `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter.
You have to manually call its constructor.

```
std::unique_ptr<void*, PtrDeleter<decltype(&CloseHandle)>> ptr{nullptr, CloseHandle}
```

In your case, it can be simplified to

```
std::unique_ptr<void*,decltype(&CloseHandle)> ptr{nullptr, CloseHandle}
```

No need to make a functor.