# Smart pointers when dealing with constructors

Tags: c++, constructor, smart-pointers

This question is in regards to my program. I was earlier using Manual Management using pointers, and now I'm trying to move to smart pointers (for all the good reasons).

In normal pointers, it was easy to call a constructor of a class by using the **new** keyword. Like in the program below:

```
Button * startButton;

startButton = new Button(int buttonID, std::string buttonName);
```

When using smart pointers, what's the alternate way of calling a constructor for a class. What I've done below gives an error:

```
std::unique_ptr<Button> startButton;

startButton = std::unique_ptr<Button>(1, "StartButton"); // Error
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error   2   error C2661: 'std::unique_ptr<Button,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
```

Comment: [make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is a wrapper around a pointer so to create a correct object of `std::unique_ptr` you should pass a pointer to its constructor:

`startButton = std::unique_ptr<Button>(new Button(1, "StartButton"));`

Since C++14 there is also a helper function `make_unique` which does this allocation for you under the hood:

```
startButton = std::make_unique<Button>(1, "StartButton");
```

Prefer to use `std::make_unique` if it is available since it is easier to read and in some cases using it is safer than using `new` directly.

Comment: The missing of `make_unique` in C++11 was a simple oversight by the committee, but you can simply build your own implementation of `make_unique` in C++11, as pointed out in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12580468/1070117) answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a compiler that supports C++14, you can use:

```
startButton = std::make_unique<Button>(1, "StartButton");
```

If you are restricted to using C++11, you need to use:

```
startButton = std::unique_ptr<Button>(new Button(1, "StartButton"));
```