# Is it possible to create a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> using the fill constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, unique-ptr

I have a class Foo with a member variable of type `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>`, which I would like to fill in the initialization list of the constructor of this class. Is this possible?

I was hoping that using the fill constructor of vector would be possible, something like this

```
Foo::Foo(int n):
    vector<unique_ptr<Bar>> (n, unique_ptr<Bar> (new Bar))
{}
```

but I think this requires copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr`, which is deleted (as it should be) (`unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete`).

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: You're right in that your attempt won't work because you only call `new Bar` once, whereas for a vector of unique pointers you need to call `new Bar` once for each element. I guess you are best off just using a loop with `emplace_back`.

Comment: Alternatively you can fill construct with empty `unique_ptr`s and then loop through calling `reset(new Bar)` on each one.

Comment: Until C++ gets iterable coroutines, I think that your best bet is a loop.

Comment: @zneak never heard of 'iterable coroutines' before. have a link to an explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is not copyable, move it!

**Solution with hard-coded objects:**

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
class Bar{};
class Foo{
    public:
    Foo():bars(get_bars()) {}
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> bars;

    private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> get_bars(){
        std::unique_ptr<Bar> inilizer_list_temp[]={std::make_unique<Bar>(),std::make_unique<Bar>(),std::make_unique<Bar>()};
        return  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>>{std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(inilizer_list_temp)),std::make_move_iterator(std::end(inilizer_list_temp))};
    }
};
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/6glen)

**Solution with Dynamic number of objects:**

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
class Bar{
    public:
    int a=5;
    };
class Foo{
    public:
    Foo():bars(get_bars(10)) {}
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> bars;

    private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> get_bars(int n){
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bar>> inilizer_list_temp;
        inilizer_list_temp.reserve(n);
        for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i){
            inilizer_list_temp.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Bar>());
        }
        return inilizer_list_temp;
    }
};
int main()
{
 Foo foo;
 for(auto const& item:foo.bars){
     std::cout << item->a;
 }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/5dfb)

And see this for more details [Can I list-initialize a vector of move-only type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468774/can-i-list-initialize-a-vector-of-move-only-type)

**EDIT:**

For C++11 users with no std::make_uniuqe:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&& ...args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580432/why-does-c11-have-make-shared-but-not-make-unique)

Comment: It seems to me that the point of the question is to avoid a loop and avoid typing out the unique_pointer creation logic for each instance. Your answer proposes hardcoding a collection of unique pointers and moving from it, which is fundamentally the same as filling out the vector by hand...

Comment: Works well with 2, what about 2000?

Comment: This looks very promising. What if I don't have C++14 support? (I think std::make_unique is a C++14 feature).