# How can I use make_unique with c++11?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I get the follow error:

> 'make_unique' is not a member of 'std'

while it write the follow code:
`std::make_unique()<Obj>(tmp)`
How can I fix it that it will be ok in c++11?

Answer (score 6):

First, `std::make_unique()<Obj>(tmp)` is incorrect syntax, it should be `std::make_unique<Obj>(tmp)` instead.

Second, [`std::make_unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) does not exist in C++11, it was added in C++14 (unlike [`std::make_shared()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), which does exist in C++11).

If you look at the [cppreference doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for `std::make_unique()`, it shows a possible implementation that (with minor tweaks) can be applied to C++11 code.  If your code doesn't need to worry about `std::unique<T[]>` support for arrays, then the simplest implementation would look like this:

```cpp
template<class T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Then you can use (without the `std::` prefix):

`make_unique<Obj>(tmp)`

Comment: Can you write the possible implementation that (with minor tweaks) can be applied to C++11 code ?

Comment: See the update to my answer. If you want array support, the only tweak I see being needed for C++11 in the [cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is changing `std::enable_if_t<...>` to `std::enable_if<...>::type`, since `std::enable_if_t` doesn't exist in C++11 either, it was also added in C++14.

Answer (score 0):

You can't: `make_unique` was added in C++14.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Boost included in Centos 7 is version 1.53, which is too old and does not have `boost::make_unique`. It appeared in Boost version 1.56.0. So the below probably isn't all that helpful. You could install a newer version of Boost manually, which is more work than just copying the `std::make_unique` implementation from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12580468/912307

---

The Boost library has an implementation `boost::make_unique`.

It seems to move around a bit in the library depending on version. If you are on a system with an old compiler (f.ex. CentOS 7) you probably also have an old version of Boost.

In 1.57.0 it is in `<boost/move/make_unique.hpp>`
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/move/reference.html#header.boost.move.make_unique_hpp

In 1.63.0 it is in `<boost/make_unique.hpp>`
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_unique.html

In 1.7.5 it is in `<boost/smart_ptr/make_unique.hpp>`
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#make_unique