# Returning an object or a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, object, pointers, return-value

In C++, should my method return an object or a pointer to an object? How to decide? What if it's an operator? How can I define?

And one more thing - if the pointer turns to be a vector, how can I find out its size after returned? And if it's impossible, as I think it is, how should I proceed to correctly return an array without this limitation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In C++, should my method return an object or a pointer to an object?
>   How to decide?

Since C++11 we have move semantics in C++ which means that it as easy as before and now also fast to return by value. That should be the default.

> What if it's an operator? How can I define?

Many operators such as `operator=` normally return a *reference* to `*this`

```
X& X::operator=(X rhs);
```

You need to look that up for each operator if you would like to comply with the usual patterns (and you should). Start here: [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

As pointed out by Ed S. return value optimization also applies (even before C++11) meaning that often object you return need neither be copied or moved.

So, this is now the way to return stuff:

```
std::string getstring(){ 
   std::string foo("hello");
   foo+=" world";
   return foo;
}
```

The fact that I made a foo object here is not my point, even if you did just do `return "hello world";` this is the way to go.

> And one more thing - if the pointer turns to be a vector, how can I
>   find out its size after returned? And if it's impossible, as I think
>   it is, how should I proceed to correctly return an array without this
>   limitation?

The same goes for all copyable or movable types in the standard (these are almost all types, for example `vectors`, `sets`, and what not), except a few exceptions. For example std::arrays do not gain from moving. They take time proportional to the amount of elements. There you could return it in a `unique_ptr` to avoid the copy.

```
typedef std::array<int,15> MyArray;
std::unique_ptr<MyArray> getArray(){ 
  std::unique_ptr<MyArray> someArrayObj(new MyArray());
  someArrayObj->at(3)=5;
  return someArrayObj;
}

int main(){
  auto x=getArray();
  std::cout << x->at(3) <<std::endl; // or since we know the index is right: (*x)[3]
}
```

**Now, to avoid ever writing `new` anymore (except for experts in rare cases) you should use a helper function called `make_unique`. That will vastly help exception safety, and is as convenient:**

```
std::unique_ptr<MyArray> getArray(){ 
  auto someArrayObj=make_unique<MyArray>();
  someArrayObj->at(3)=5;
  return someArrayObj;
}
```

For more motivation and the (really short) implementation of `make_unique`, have a look here:
 [make_unique and perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding)

### Update

Now `make_unique` is part of the C++14 standard. If you don't have it, you can find and use the whole implementation from the [proposal by S.T.L.:](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3588.txt)

[Ideone example on how to do that](http://ideone.com/dNxCJf)

Comment: And even before move semantics we had RVO, with hit or miss support for RVO across translation units.

Comment: Will `return "hello";` really break that? i.e. does the return value need to be named?

Comment: No need to use `std::array::at()` when you *know* that the index is not out of range.

Comment: @EdS. True, but as an example, the syntax for `[]` on a pointer is not as nice ;)

Comment: @JohanLundberg: I suppose we'll just have to disagree there, but ok, fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

> In C++, should my method return an object or a pointer to an object?

You should return an object by default. Usual exceptions are functions that return a subclass of a given class, and when returning nothing is a legal option for a function<sup>1</sup>.

> What if it's an operator?

Operators return references or objects; although it is technically possible to return pointers from overloaded operators, it is not usually done.

> And one more thing - if the pointer turns to be a vector, how can I find out it's size after returned?

I think you meant an *array* rather than a *vector*, because `std::vector` has a `size()` member function returning the size of the vector. Finding the size of a variable-length array is indeed not possible.

> And if it's impossible, as I think it is, how should I proceed to correctly return an array without this limitation?

You should use `std::vector`, it does not limit you on the size or the type of elements that go into it.

---

<sup>1</sup> In which case you return `NULL` or `nullptr` in C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is some specific reason to use plain pointers, always return something memory-safe. In an estimated 95% of all cases, simply returning objects is fine, and then return-by-value is definitely the canonical thing to do (simple, efficient, good!).

The remaining 5% are mostly when the returned object is runtime-polymorphic; such an object can't be returned by value in C++ since that would happen on the stack. In such a case, you should return a *smart pointer* to the new object, in C++11 the standard choice is `std::unique_ptr`. There is also the case when you want to *optionally* return something, but that's IMO a case for a specific container, not for pointers, `boost::optional` or [something like that](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/cxx-lambdalike/blob/master/include/maybe.hpp).

Comment: `HASKELLLIKE_CLASS_MAYBE_MONAD` is a pretty cute name.