# Return a pointer or value when objects are large

Tags: c++, matrix, constexpr

Say we make a `Matrix<n, m>` class, that stores nxm integers in a member variable `std::array<std::array<int, m>, n> inner;`. Now there are two ways of making add:

**Method 1**) Returning by value (`constexpr` is possible)

```
template<int n, int m> class Matrix {
    ...
    constexpr Matrix add(const Matrix& that) const {
        matrix ret;
        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < m; x++)
                ret.inner[y][x] = this->inner[y][x] + that.inner[y][x];
        return ret;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Method 2**) Returning a pointer (`constexpr` is not possible)

```
template<int n, int m> class Matrix {
    ...
    Matrix *add(const Matrix& that) const {
        Matrix *ret = new Matrix();
        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < m; x++)
                ret->inner[y][x] = this->inner[y][x] + that.inner[y][x];
        return ret;
    }
    ...
}
```

My program need to do arithmetic with `1000x1000` matrices (images), so using **Method 1** I get a stackoverflow immediately. My program also works with small `4x4` matrices (density matrices in quantum computations) that need to be computed at compile time, so using **Method 2** is impossible in these `constexpr` initializations.

*Question*: do I need to make two versions of every method returning `Matrix`? (one returning a `Matrix` and the other returning a `Matrix*`) This will be a lot of duplicate code. How common is this problem? Is there an alternative way of using the heap so that **Method 2** is also possible from `constexpr`?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13213936/815305) mentions that move-semantics have shifted the preference a little bit to **Method 1**. But how about the resulting stack-overflows?

Comment: Don't use `std::array<std::array<int, m>, n>`, use an appropriately sized `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: That is not possible unfortunately. I do calls to an external dll (the Math Kernel Library) that expects the matrices to be stored like `std::array`.

Comment: the part that actually does cause the overlow is not in the code you posted. If `Matrix` does manage the dynamic memory you do not need to dynamically allocate the `Matrix`

Comment: If you mean Intel's MKL, it uses one-dimensional arrays in the C interface and does not have a C++ interface.

Comment: Only 1000x1000? If you don't have too many threads, or you are using 64-bit binary, just increase stack size.

Comment: @molbdnilo: I use an `extern "C"` call to the dll to use the library
@AlexGuteniev: Yes, the problem is that parts are also multithreaded and I am afraid of the extra required memory, especially because I might increase the resolution to a sqaure matrix of dimension `10000`

Comment: @Carucel `std::array` and `std::vector` both store their elements consecutively. It's the same layout. It shouldn't be a problem using an `extern C` interface.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you, I didn't know that. I prefer to use `std::array`, because of performance, but if there is no other way, I will change to using `std::vector` then.

Comment: @Carucel It's not clear what performance gains you are expecting. But if you want to move an `std::array` off the stack, you'll end up with an `std::vector`. If you want to avoid dynamic memory allocation or trying to keep locality with stack objects, any solution that moves your data off the stack will break those anyway.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, I was thinking about `std::vector` managing it's size, which can be variable, but maybe there is no performance gain indeed if I know the size in advance.

Comment: @Carucel If you don't want `std::vector`'s size and capacity management, you could use `std::unique_ptr<std::array<T>>` instead. But you'll have to implement copy construction, copy assignment and comparison yourself.

Answer (score 3):

My proposition:

```
template<size_t n, size_t m>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix& operator+=(const Matrix& other)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

template<size_t n, size_t m>
Matrix<n, m> constexpr operator+(Matrix<n, m> x, Matrix<n, m> const& y)
{
    x += y;
    return x;
}

template<size_t n, size_t m>
std::unique_ptr<Matrix<n, m>> add(Matrix<n, m> const* x, Matrix<n, m> const* y)
{
    auto result = std::make_unique<n, m>(*x);
    *result += *y;
    return std::unique_result;
}
```

Now you can use addition by value for small matrices:

```
Matrix<10, 12> m1, m2;
auto m3 = m1 + m2;
```

and large matrices you could allocate dynamically:

```
auto pm1 = std::make_unique<Matrix<12, 10>>();
auto pm2 = std::make_unique<Matrix<12, 10>>();
auto pm3 = add(pm1.get(), pm2.get());
```

Or even:

```
auto pm3 = std::make_unique<Matrix<12, 10>>(pm1);
*pm3 += *pm2;
```

Comment: I think you forgot the actual addition  in `operator+=`. Maybe put a placeholder comment at least.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's inside the class... Admitted, I don't add anything inside, but for demonstration that should suffice.