# Safe to use vector.emplace_back( new MyPointer ); Could failure inside vector lead to leaked memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, stdvector

Is it safe to use

```
vector.emplace_back( new MyPointer() );
```

Or could an exception thrown or some failure inside vector cause memory leak?

Would it be better to do some form of the following, where you put the pointer in a temporary unique_ptr first.

```
vector.emplace_back( std::unique_ptr<MyPointer>( new MyPointer() ) );
```

So if a vector failure occurs the temporary unique_ptr will still clean up the memory?

Comment: I suggest `std::make_unique` once some C++14 support is available or your own if not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is **not** safe and would create a memory leak if you use the first version. The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) says that if an exception is thrown, the call to `emplace` has no effect - which means the plain pointer you passed in is never deleted.

You can use

```
vector.emplace_back( std::unique_ptr<MyPointer>( new MyPointer() ) );
```

or with C++14 you can use

```
vector.emplace_back( std::make_unique<MyPointer>() );
```

or, if C++14 is not yet available, just roll your own version of `make_unique`. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357).

Comment: you also need to change the type of the `vector` with the above.  If that is infeasible, you can store the added element outside in a smart pointer, add it, then detech if it worked.

Comment: You mean 'C++11' instead of 'C++14'?

Comment: @fnc12 No, I meant C++14. [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) was not available/standardized in C++11.

Answer (score 4):

No, the first scenario is not safe and will leak memory if the `vector` throws an exception.

The second scenario will not compile, as a `std::unique_ptr<T>` cannot be implicitly converted to `T*`.  Even if it could, this scenario is arguably worse than the first, because it will add the pointer to your vector, then immediately delete the object being pointed to.  You will be left with a vector containing a dangling pointer.

Without changing the type of your `std::vector` (which I assume is `std::vector<MyPointer*>`) there are two ways to make this code exception safe.

Using C++11:

```
auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<MyPointer>(new MyPointer());
vector.emplace_back(ptr.get());
ptr.release();
```

Or the more verbose C++03 way:

```
MyPointer* ptr = new MyPointer();
try
{
  vector.push_back(ptr);
}
catch (...)
{
  delete ptr;
  throw;
}
```

If you are able to change the type of your `std::vector<MyPointer*>` then the easiest method are those suggested by Daniel Frey above:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyPointer>> vector;
vector.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<MyPointer>(new MyPointer()));
```

Or with C++14:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyPointer>> vector;
vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<MyPointer>());
```