# How to turn vector of raw pointers into a vector of unique pointers?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, raii, raw-pointer

```
#include <vector>

enum ListOfGameStates
{
    // List of game states
};

class GameState()
{
    public:
        GameStates(); // Initializes protected (global) variables
        virtual ListOfGameStates run() = 0;
    protected:
        // Heavyweigh resource managers containing all resources and other global vars
}

class GameStateManager()
{
    public:
        GameStateManager();  // Creates all game states
        ~GameStateManager(); // Deletes all game states
        void run();          // Switches from one state to another state
    private:
        // A vector of raw pointers to game states. GameState is a base class.
        std::vector<GameState*> game_states_container;
}
```

I want to get rid off raw pointers so that I could have no worries about exceptions and clean-up. Is there an **easy simple solution** (I am a really dumb teen) or is it not worth it? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was confused because 'push_back' wouldn't work. Now it's fine

Comment: Generally, it is probably a good idea to include what "wouldn't work" in your question.

Comment: Looks like your `GameState` class needs a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: @Galik Why? Game states have no pointers, all big objects are global. Others are self-destroying smart classes.

Comment: `GameState` has a pure virtual function meaning you will only be using subclasses and those subclasses will be deleted (by the smart pointer) from a base pointer. Without a virtual dtor that's undefined behavior.

Comment: Good books: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply change your vector to:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState>> game_states_container;
```

And get rid of any `delete` in your destructor. In fact you can probably get rid of the destructor entirely unless it has other jobs to do.

`unique_ptr` is not copyable but it is movable so it is worth having some understanding of C++11 move-semantics. When you want to add a `unique_ptr` to your container you can use `push_back` providing you pass a temporary, e.g the return value of a function:

```
game_states_container.push_back(createGameState());
game_states_container.push_back(std::make_unique<GameStateA>());  // C++14
```

Or if you have a local `unique_ptr` variable you can use `std::move` to move it into the vector:

```
std::unique_ptr<GameState> game_state = std::make_unique<GameStateA>();  // C++14
// auto game_state = std::unique_ptr<GameState>(new GameStateA);  // C++11
...
game_states_container.push_back(std::move(game_state));
```

It is good practice to put the raw pointers in `unique_ptr` as soon as you `new` them (or preferably use `std::make_unique`). Otherwise, if an exception is thrown between allocation and wrapping in `unique_ptr` you have a memory leak.

It is unrelated to `unique_ptr` but your `GameState` class [should have a virtual destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).

<kbd>[Live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/rJc1Pp6u8gTXvyhI)</kbd>

Comment: Try it and see. Also read your C++11 book to the end before continuing.

Comment: I guess I need another book.

Comment: Actually, Chris, your answer is now a bit misleading: `push_back` will work just fine on `unique_ptr`, even without `std::move` – as long as the object being pushed is a temporary. `emplace_back` isn’t necessary because `unique_ptr` is noncopyable, it’s necessary because there’s no implicit conversion from a raw pointer to `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hope that is less misleading now.

Comment: @Chris It’s perfect now.

Comment: Dunno if its worth mentioning, but emplace_back forwards its args to the fundamental T constructor when emplacement is being done. Thus the equivalent to the other methods of insertion isn't `emplace_back()`, its `emplace_back(new GameStateDerivative);` The constructor for `std::unique_ptr<>` will receive the allocated object and take ownership, avoiding the need to later `reset(new GameStateDerivative)` (which you can still do anyway, of course). Also, `make_unique` is a C++14 feature, for those still in the C++11 trenches (i.e. most of us).

Comment: @WhozCraig Now we have `make_unique` (which is available Visual Studio 2013) I avoid using `new` entirely and prefer `push_back(std::make_unique<GameStateDerivative>())`.

Comment: Yeah, "now we have make_unique" - unfortunately, "we* don't yet. Jeezo I'm still stuck in the half-baked 03x derivation MS spun with VS2010 at work (yeah,  ugh). Company entrenchment FTL. *

Comment: @WhozCraig, but what does `emplace_back(new GameStateDerivative)` do if the vector tries to reallocate and throws `bad_alloc`? The constructor for `unique_ptr` only takes ownership if the vector gets far enough to use that constructor. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19414387/981959

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think I will get rid of the `emplace_back` suggestion entirely I can't think of a good reason for using it in this context.

Comment: @ChrisDrew, agreed.  `emplace_back` is useful to avoid a temporary, but shouldn't be used just to perform an implicit conversion that would fail to compile otherwise.