# C++ : Allocation of an array attribute in a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, allocation

I would like to know, if I have a class with an array attribute whose size is not the same for all instances :

```
class myObject{

private:
    int size;
    int* array;

// other methods/attributes

};
```

Is it obligatory allocated using new ?

```
explicit myObject(int size = 0):size(size){
    array = new int[size];
}
```

Even if in the main(), I always use constant parameters to create the instances of the class ? (Meaning I know every array size at compile time).

```
int main{
    myObject object (5);
    return 0;
}
```

Apparently something like :

```
private:
    int size;
    int array[size];
```

wont work, no ?

That means that array attribute whose size are not constant of the class are obligatory on the heap ?

Thank you for your answers,

Comment: If you need array of varying size then I would look into vector/map instead

Comment: I don't need an array whose size vary.
The size if fixed for each array, it's juste that it's not the same for every instance. For exemple for object1 it's 5 and for object2 it's 10.

Comment: I perfectly understand that, and yet you could just define a vector and then allocate it with different sizes for each child. That will save you the need of using template.

Comment: Okay, truth is I'm currently learning and I haven't reach the part about STL and classic containers.

Comment: Nitpick: your class does not have an array attribute. It has a pointer. You can make it point to a dynamically allocated array, but it is still a pointer. It is important to distinguish pointers from arrays.

Comment: not a problem, we are here to help! And for future if you are replying to someone - tag them with @name so they will get a notification (unless they own question/answer, then they will get it anyway).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that while `std::vector` is probably most appropriate at the moment, despite the fact it can change size, there is a proposal in progress for a `std::dynarray` which is fixed-size. It should be usable within the next year or so (but not part of the standard until C++17).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That class contains no array.  What you called `array` is a pointer; you cannot store any `int`s in it.  If you really do just store a pointer, you'll have to allocate the memory yourself *somehow*; it can't magically appear.  You'll also have to deallocate it yourself, and make sure that copying and assigning `myObject` objects doesn't cause any issues.

However, it's unlikely that a pointer is really the best way to do things.  The standard library provides the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class template which lets you use almost exactly the syntax you want:

```
class myObject {
    std::vector<int> vector;

public:
    myObject() {};
    explicit myObject(std::size_t n) : vector(n) {}
};
```

With this in place you can create `myObject`s and they'll have the right amount of storage ready for them.  It'll likely be dynamically allocated using `operator new[]`, just like if you'd do it manually, but you don't have to worry about copying or deleting it.

```
int main() {
    myObject a; // default-constructed, vector is empty.
    myObject b(10); // std::size_t constructor, vector has 10 elements.
} // scope exit, b and a destroyed.
```

You can use the `vector` member much like if it was an array; the only thing it does not support is implicit decay to pointer, but the `data` member function makes up for even that.

As an alternative, if you always know the size at compile-time you can change the class into a class template and make the size a template parameter:

```
template<std::size_t N>
class myObject{
    std::array<int, N> array;

    // other methods/attributes
};
```

However, note that you now cannot use `myObject<10>` to a function expecting `myObject<20>`.

It is unlikely that you want more control than the above possibilities provide -- `std::vector` can be given an allocator, so it can do almost all work for you -- you could use [`std::unique_ptr<int[]>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13512344/559931) and [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) together to make things work for you.  However, if you need this kind of power, you probably know it yourself.

As a closing note, if you're just learning C++ and your book doesn't cover `std::vector`s somewhere early on, perhaps it's best to get a different book; they're one of the most commonly-useful data structures in the standard library and definitely not something to be left in an appendix.

Comment: @ Anton Golov & Jarod42 :
Thanks for the answers.
Do you have any recommandations concerning learning books ?

Comment: @Demod: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Jarod42: Yeah, if I'm suggesting unique_ptr might as well, thanks.

Comment: @Demod: If you're a beginner programmer, try [C++ Primer](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321714113).  (Though I'm not sure I'd recommend C++ then...)

Comment: @AntonGolov 
I already programmed in Java, C and Matlab. But I'm not a computer science student, I'm more into applied mathematics, and I use programming to do calculations and implementations. Currently I want to learn C++ as I need a specific data structure that has been implemented in C++. Sadly, I dont really have the time to go into a 1K-pages book right now.

Comment: @Demod: Well, if you need something quick, get [Accelerated C++](http://www.amazon.com/dp/020170353X/).  It's significantly shorter, and the fact that it's somewhat old probably won't matter for you anyway.

Comment: @AntonGolov Thank you, I'll start reading it. I'll go later into a more detailed book (like Primer) if I feel the need (and hopefully if I have the time ^^' )

Answer (score 0):

If you need a variable sized array as a member of a class, don't use built-in arrays directly. Instead, use `std::vector<T>`, e.g.:

```
class myObject {
    std::vector<int> array;
public:
    explicit myObject(int size = 0): array(size){}
};
```

You can get the `std:vector<int>`'s size using `array.size()`, i.e., there is no need to store the size separately. Also, the content is automatically default initialized.