# Is there a way to make instantiation with unique_ptr less verbose?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a class with two `std::unique_ptr` members. I want to set those members through the constructor.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Assignment> assignment{new Assignment{
       std::unique_ptr<Variable>{new Variable{"a"}},
       std::unique_ptr<Expression>{new Variable{"b"}}
}};
```

With regular pointers, I would just have done this:

```
auto assignment = new Assignment{new Variable{"a"}, new Variable{"b"}};
delete assignment;
```

Can I make the smart pointer version less verbose somehow? I was hoping something like this might work.

```
std::unique_ptr<Assignment> assignment{new Variable{"a"},{new Variable{"b"}};
```

However, the constructor of `unique_ptr` is explicit, so it doesn't.

Comment: You could provide your own implementation of [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) to make some things a little easier.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to implement `make_unique()`, I'd suggest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding. Also, note that in your second and third examples, you will leak memory if the construction of the second `new Variable` fails. (Which is part of the whole point of std::make_unique and std::make_shared).

Comment: @sharth: That could also be the case in the first example. I am not sure, but I believe the compiler can interleave the creation of the two `unique_ptr` arguments doing first the two `new` then the construction of the `unique_ptr`, potentially leaking memory. You need to interleave a function call (`make_unique`) to guarantee that no memory is leaked.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I believe you are correct.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas If I read the standard correctly, no.  In list initialization, the elements of the list are evaluated in order (possibly a first for C++), and the evaluation of each element is sequenced before the evaluation of the following.  See 8.5.4/4.

Comment: Why do you have to allocate `Variable{"a"}` and `Variable{"b"}` on the heap? As I see it, you don't access them through a pointer to the base class so you can probably get rid of those two `new`s. If not, then please revise the question and add more details.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks for the reference. I agree with your reading and now believe that it would be guaranteed not to leak.

Comment: User of GCC should [beware that it still does not process braced-init-lists in the standard-mandated order](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51253) in some circumstances.

Comment: btw most of the time you dont need up so try using values if possible

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl What's "up"? I'm using pointers because I want to use polymorphism.

Comment: unique_ptr, and anyway for me it is rare to need 2 up of the same type but i guess you know what you are doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a perfect forwarding constructor an option?

```
// If you aren't using make_unique, you're doing it wrong.
template <typename T, typename...Args>
inline std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&...args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>{new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)};
}

struct Variable {
    std::string name_;

    Variable(std::string name) : name_{std::move(name)} {}
};

struct Assignment {
    std::unique_ptr<Variable> a_, b_;

    template <typename T, typename U>
    Assignment(T&& a, U&& b) :
      a_{make_unique<Variable>(std::forward<T>(a))},
      b_{make_unique<Variable>(std::forward<U>(b))} {}
};

auto assignment = make_unique<Assignment>("a", "b");
```

Simplifies the syntax quite a bit, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would probably be

```
std::unique_ptr<Assignment> assignment {
   new Assignment{Variable{"a"}, Variable{"b"}}};
```

Of course, that requires a suitable `Assignment(Variable&&, Variable&&)` overload.