# Eclipse Mars: Symbol 'unique_ptr' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

Using Eclipse Mars, I am getting the `Symbol 'unique_ptr' could not be resolved` error. I tried adding `-std=c++11` to CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings, but this didn't help. The error goes away when I reopen Eclipse, but if I make a modification to the code, the error comes back.

One simple code sample:

```
std::unique_ptr<String> p1;
```

Comment: Did you #include <memory> ?

Comment: I did, yes, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. In Eclipse Mars open `Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Settings > Discovery > CDT GCC Build-in Compiler Settings`
2. Append `-std=c++11` to the *Command to get compiler specs*
3. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>
4. Rebuild the index: `Project > C/C++ Index > Rebuild`

Comment: For me it was necessary to

5. Restart Eclipse

For whatever reason?!

Comment: And in my case I had to rebuild the index ( Right-Click on Project > Index > Rebuild ) in the end.

Comment: Also, std::make_unique is only defined in C++14 and later compilers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609271/errormake-unique-is-not-a-member-of-std).