# List of unique_ptr, for a derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I want to create a `list<unique_ptr<Base>> listOfBaseUniquePtr`. This will be able to give me both:
1. Unique ptrs, and
2. Polymorphism. I whould be able to call each derived class virtual function.

Something doesn't work for me. Take a look in the following code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base {
};

list<unique_ptr<Base>> listOfBaseUniquePtr;

template <typename T>
class Derived: public Base {

};

int main() {

    listOfBaseUniquePtr.push_back(new Derived<int>()); // <--- error
}
```

Error:

> main.cpp:19:53: error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘std::list >::push_back(Derived*)’
>
>        listOfBaseUniquePtr.push_back(new Derived()); // <--- error
>
>                                                        ^ main.cpp:19:53: note: candidates are: In file included from
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/list:63:0,
>
>                    from main.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1015:7: note: void std::list<_Tp,
>
>   _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr; _Alloc = std::allocator
>
>   std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr]
>
>          push_back(const value_type& __x)
>
>          ^ /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1015:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Derived*’ to ‘const value_type&
>   {aka const std::unique_ptr&}’
>   /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1020:7: note: void std::list<_Tp,
>   _Alloc>::push_back(std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type&&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr; _Alloc = std::allocator
>   std::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = std::unique_ptr]
>          push_back(value_type&& __x)
>          ^ /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_list.h:1020:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Derived*’ to
>   ‘std::list >::value_type&& {aka
>   std::unique_ptr&&}’ make[2]:
>   [CMakeFiles/uniqueptr.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1 make[1]:
>   [CMakeFiles/uniqueptr.dir/all] Error 2 make: [all] Error 2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `push_back(make_unique<Derived<int>>())` should do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the signature of `push_back()`, you will see that there are two overloads. One takes a `std::unique_ptr<T> const&` and the other a `std::unique_ptr<T>&&`.

The expression `new Derived<int>()` returns a `Derived<int>*` type; clearly that is not either of the previously mentioned types; none of the overloads have a `Derived<int>*` parameter.

You can do two things:

Replace

```
listOfBaseUniquePtr.push_back(new Derived<int>());
```

With

```
listOfBaseUniquePtr.push_back( std::make_unique<Derived<int>>() );
```

Or, use the `emplace()` family of member functions of `std::list<T>`; here's an example:

```
listOfBaseUniquePtr.emplace_back( new Derived<int> );
```

Your base classes should always have a virtual destructor if classes that derive from that base class are going to be deleted through a pointer of the base class. Your base class' definition should be:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find this `std::make_unique` because I'm on g++4.8, and not 4.9 :(.
So I used this implementation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609271/errormake-unique-is-not-a-member-of-std

Comment: @hudac While I'd recommend using `std::make_unique` you could also simply do `listOfBaseUniquePtr.push_back( std::unique_ptr<Derived<int>>( new Derived<int> ) );`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique):

```
listOfBaseUniquePtr.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived<int>>());
```

also dont forget to add virtual destructor to your Base:

```
virtual ~Base(){}
```

otherwise ~Derived constructor will not be called if destroyed using base class pointer.