# Android Studio can't find reference to make_unique, but the project compiles fine

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, libc++

First off, here are my SDK versions just for clarity:

- Android Studio Version = 3.3.2
- Android SDK Build-Tools = up to 28.0.3
- Android SDK Platform-Tools = 28.0.1
- Android SDK Tools = 26.1.1
- LLDB = 3.1 (libc++, which supports c++17)
- CMake = 3.10.2.4988404
- NDK = 19.1.5304403

Essentially, I'm attempting to use `std::make_unique<>()` in my native-lib.cpp file.  I have included `<memory>`, where make_unique is defined in.  Android Studio gives an error in the editor, saying: `Cannot resolve namespace member 'make_unique'`.  However if I build the project, it compiles just fine.

I've researched this, and made some attempts to solve this via modifying my compiler options (by adding `-std=c++14`, and `-std=c++17` to my `build.gradle` file), as well adding the following line (to `CMakeLists.txt`) from the [oboe tutorial](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/RhythmGame/CMakeLists.txt):

```
target_compile_options(native-lib
    PRIVATE -std=c++14 -Wall -Werror "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-Ofast>")
```

Neither of these even matter anyway as libc++ should support c++17 functionality.  I can compile/build my project fine even with this red item in my IDE.

I have also tried deleting my .gradle, and .idea directories then cleaned, re-synced, and built the project again with no avail.

Is this a potential bug with Android Studio, or does anyone else notice this problem?  Any help would be appreciated, but I suppose at this point I'll just have to either ignore it or use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24609331/10013384

Comment: The IDE is *not* the compiler and it's errors ("red items") are *not* authoritative.

Comment: Please don't re-add another definition, as this is not the problem you face. Which version of AndroidStudio do you have?

Comment: @elcuco Android Studio v. 3.3.2