# Make iterator dereference object

Tags: c++

I have a simple container class such as:

```
class SimpleContainer {
    using iterator = std::vector<Contained*>::iterator;

    std::vector<Contained*> items_; // Note that 'Contained' is polymorphic.

public:
    iterator begin() { return items_.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return items_.end(); }    
};
```

Easy enough. But when I use it in, say, a `for` loop, I have to manually dereference the item, as in:

```
SimpleContainer container;
for (auto item : container) {
    cout << *item << endl; // Dereferencing here is ugly
}
```

Is there a simple way to make the iterator automatically dereference for me, or do I need to write a new iterator that has that behavior?

Comment: I would argue that dereferencing here isn't ugly -- it's **idiomatic**.  Writing (or using from Boost eg) an automatically-dereferencing iterator would obfuscate what's actually happening, making maintenance more difficult.

Comment: I wondered if that might not be the case. Still fairly new to c++, so don't have my sea legs quite yet. Thanks

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear (given you're new to C++), you are aware that `item` here isn't an `iterator`, but a *dereferenced* `iterator` -- in other words, it's a type that resembles a `Contained*`, since that's what's in the `vector`.

Comment: Yeah, that much I get at least. I just thought it would be nicer for the client-end developer if the object came out of the iterator pre-dereferenced. But it sounds like its normal for a container of pointers to return a pointer.

Comment: While we're on the subject, please don't store raw pointers in your containers, or ever (disclaimer applied) write `new` or `delete`.  Instead, store `unique_ptr <Contained>` or (if you must) `shared_ptr <Contained>`, created with `make_unique` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding)) or `make_shared`.

Comment: I've been wondering about that. Thanks for that as well! Should I replace all functions that take pointers (for example the add function for my container above) with `std::unique/shared_ptr`? Or is there some sort of policy on that?

Comment: You should generally pass either references to objects, `shared_ptr`s or `weak_ptr`s (constructed from a `shared_ptr`)

Comment: That being said, IMO there are still not-so-uncommon cases where passing a raw pointer is best -- just be clear and consistent about ownership semantics.

Answer (score 3):

If using boost is acceptable, the `indirect_iterator` is created just for this purpose. Use

```
using iterator = boost::indirect_iterator<std::vector<Contained*>::iterator>;
```

Then you will need to modify `begin()` and `end()` with

```
iterator begin() { return boost::make_indirect_iterator(items_.begin(); }
```

More details at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html

Comment: Good to know. Trying to stick with just the c++11 STL, but good to know that's there.

Comment: `s/STL/standard library/`

Answer (score -1):

You sure that you need to store pointers in your container? I would implement your code like this:

```
std::vector<Contained> items_;
```

in this case you don't need to de-reference item object.

Comment: Contained is polymorphic, so I think I have to use a pointer.