# Why can't I use unique_ptr with fread?

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

If you run the code below `fread` will return with 0. If you change `p` to use `buf` instead of the `unique_ptr` it will work. Why? I ran this in MSVC 2013

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[1024 * 32];
    auto buf2 = make_unique<char>(1024 * 32);

    {
        memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);
        FILE *f = fopen("tmpfile", "wb");
        printf("write = %d\n", fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof buf, f));
        fclose(f);
    }

    //char*p = 0 ? buf2.get() : buf;
    //char*p = buf;
    char*p = buf2.get();

    FILE *f = fopen("tmpfile", "r+b");

    printf("read = %d\n", fread(p, 1, sizeof buf, f));

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `buf2` is holding a single character

Comment: @PiotrS.: Is it? How do I allocate an array? and I can't believe I'm not getting warnings

Comment: `auto buf2 = unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[1024 * 32]);`

Comment: `make_unique<char>(1024 * 32)` is complete nonsense.

Comment: Or `auto buf2 = make_unique<char[]>(1024 * 32);`

Comment: @PiotrS. that one line gives me a dozen compile errors. `unique_ptr<char> buf2(new char[1024 * 32]);` seems to work. I'll accept it as an answer

Comment: @DieterLücking: It appears this compiler doesn't warn me of this nonsense!

Comment: @acidzombie24 `unique_ptr<char> buf2(new char[1024 * 32]);` is not valid, as it does not use `delete[]` operator for freeing the memory

Comment: @Praetorian/Dieter: I'm a little surprise `char[]` works. That makes me think its a pointer to a pointer

Comment: @acidzombie24: Why that? It's an explicit overload for arrays of unkown length.

Comment: I don't see how pointer to pointer comes into the picture. `unique_ptr` has a partial specialization for `T[]` that handles allocation/deallocation using `new[]/delete[]`. That's what you're using when you call `make_unique<char[]>(...)`

Comment: compare: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dae2a6f2427468a9

Comment: @Praetorian Do you want to actually write an answer so I can upvote that instead of your comments?

Comment: @Barry I'm waiting to upvote an answer from Piotr :) He solved the problem before I even came across the question.

Comment: Why not `std::vector`?

Comment: @Praetorian I'm not writing the answer, and I really like the `make_unique<char[]>(1024 * 32);` syntax I didnt know about, so go on

Comment: @milleniumbug: Do you know a way I can have a vector be 1024*32 length without filling it with 0s?

Comment: Wait, does `make_unique<T[]>` take a size or the actual elements? [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) says the size, but Lavavej's code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding) is the elements.

Comment: the standardized *array version* of `make_unique<T[]>` is `return unique_ptr<T>(new typename remove_extent<T>::type[n]());` with `n` as the only argument of type `size_t`, so it is size, not elements

Comment: So many comments, so little question/answer upvotes. Not that anyone will see this comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
auto buf2 = make_unique<char>(1024 * 32);
```

allocates a single `char` and initializes it to `(1024 * 32) mod 256` (assuming 8 bit char). To allocate an array of `char`s containing those many elements, use

```
auto buf2 = unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[1024 * 32]);
//or
auto buf2 = make_unique<char[]>(1024 * 32);
```

After making that change your program should behave as expected.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0d294ec41f51f54)

---

And you might as well use `unique_ptr` to manage the `FILE` as well.

Define a deleter and an alias

```
auto fcloser = [](FILE *f) { ::fclose(f); };
using unique_file = std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(fcloser)>;
```

And then use it as

```
unique_file f(fopen("tmpfile", "wb"), fcloser); // use f.get() to access FILE*
```

You can even define a factory function to cut down on the verbosity some more.