# How to assign a value of a string to a std::unique_ptr<std::string>?

Tags: c++, string, unique-ptr

After declaring an `std::unique_ptr<std::string>` but without assigning it (so it contains an `std::nullptr` to begin with) - how to assign a value to it (i.e. I no longer want it to be holding `std::nullptr`)? Neither of the methods I've attempted work.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> my_str_ptr;
my_str_ptr = new std::string(another_str_var); // compiler error
*my_str_ptr = another_str_var; // runtime error
```

where `another_str_var` is an `std::string` that is declared and assigned earlier.

Clearly my understanding of what `std::unique_ptr` is doing is woefully inadequate...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) in C++14 to create and move assign without the explicit `new` or having to repeat the type name `std::string`

```
my_str_ptr = std::make_unique<std::string>(another_str_var);
```

You could [reset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) it, which replaces the managed resources with a new one (in your case there's no actual deletion happening though).

```
my_str_ptr.reset(new std::string(another_str_var));
```

You could create a new `unique_ptr` and move assign it into your original, though this always strikes me as messy.

```
my_str_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::string>{new std::string(another_str_var)};
```

Comment: One more is to use `swap` instead of `operator=`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Making use of the first method for now, I'll try out the C++14 version after changing my compiler settings. (Can't accept the answer yet though...)

Comment: @Kvothe If you look around you can find the motivation for using `make_unique`, being able to almost never write `new` is pretty cool.

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512344/315052) for an implementation of `make_unique`.

Comment: Why doesn't `auto result = std::unique_ptr<std::string> {std::string {}};` work?

Comment: @jrwren this question is how to modify an existing `unique_ptr`. Your suggestion is missing a `new`, but is otherwise a valid way to create a new `unique_ptr`, though I'd say favor `auto result = std::make_unique<std::string>();` so you don't have to repeat the type.