# Shared Ptr vs Normal Ptr: Object Creation After Declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, shared-memory, shared-ptr

With normal pointers, I can declare a pointer and then set it equal to a new object, however with shared pointers I am unable to do that. Why?

```
#include <memory>
struct node{
    int num;
    node* next;
};
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<node> new_node1 = NULL; // WORKS
    new_node1 = new node;   // ERROR, why?
    node* new_node2 = NULL; //WORKS
    new_node2 = new node;   //WORKS

    return 0;
}
```

Why can't we create a new object for a shared pointer? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: [`reset()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset).

Comment: How would I use reset() to do this?

Comment: `new_node1.reset (new node);` or `new_node1 = std::make_shared <node> ();`

Comment: The answer to that was a click away. Lazy :\

Comment: The short answer to your first question is that if you could do so easily, terrible things would happen. Consider `Foo *f = new Foo(); bar(f); bar(f);`. Now, what happens if `bar` takes a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`? (Think about the destruction of the temporary shared pointer.) You want to know for sure where and when you are constructing a `shared_ptr` because that takes over control of the lifetime of the underlying object.

Comment: [same question with unique_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992806/)

Answer (score 4):

```
std::shared_ptr<node> n(new node);
n.reset(new node);
n = std::make_shared<node>();
```

You should [prefer `make_shared`](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the constructor that would be called during the `operator=()` call is marked as `explicit`.

To work around this:

```
new_node1 = std::shared_ptr<node>(new node);
```

Or:

```
new_node1 = std::make_shared<node>();
```