# Weird memory leak in Visual Studio C++ project

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, memory-leaks

I use `unique_ptr`. For creating this poiters, I use this code snippet:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&& ...args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); //line 44
}
```

I test my project for memory leaks with help [built-in memory leak checker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx).

I get the following result:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
my_header.h(44) : {228} normal block at 0x008AD568, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > A0 CB 8A 00 01 00 00 00 
my_header.h(44) : {226} normal block at 0x008AD5B8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <        > 00 D6 8A 00 00 00 00 00 
/////////////////this error repeats many times
```

Also, I use [deleaker](http://www.deleaker.com/). This tool says, that there is no memory leaks.

Comment: Don't use this for array types?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I use make_unique 3 times in my project. make_unique always create raw pointer.
I see this code - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512344/1756750 My error is reproduced with this code too.

Comment: Using `return` with a `unique_ptr` automatically calls [move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) -- I take it this is what you want?

Comment: @erip, unfortunately, I don't use `return` with a `unique_ptr`. I just create unique_ptr<type> and call `release()`.

Comment: @Denis, in your code `make_unique` does indeed `return` a `unique_ptr`. Perhaps the memory-leak checker thinks that this reference within `make_unique` is a leak, when it actually isn't because ownership is moving to the assignee when called.

Comment: @erip, Right. Initially, I misunderstood you, sorry.

Comment: Wait, why are you calling `release()`?

Comment: @erip Technically, it doesn't call `std::move`.

Comment: @T.C. would this be a case of RVO and that's why `std::move` isn't called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using [**`release()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) unless you're handing off the pointer-raw to someone else (hopefully another `std::unique_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr`, etc). Instead you should be using [**`reset()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset), or just letting scope-exit destroy the managed object for you.

The simplest example using your code that demonstrates bad and good:

**Bad : Using `release()`**

```
#include <memory>

namespace
{
    template<typename T, typename ...Args>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&& ...args)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = make_unique<int>(5);
    ptr.release();
}
```

Valgrind Output

```
==29012== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 87
==29012==    at 0x10003B51B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==29012==    by 0x1001CD43D: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==29012==    by 0x10000147B: std::__1::unique_ptr<int, std::__1::default_delete<int> > (anonymous namespace)::make_unique<int, int>(int&&) (in ./Sample C++)
==29012==    by 0x100001337: main (in ./Sample C++)
==29012== 
==29012== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29012==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks
==29012==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29012==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29012==    still reachable: 192 bytes in 6 blocks
==29012==         suppressed: 35,164 bytes in 435 blocks
==29012== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==29012== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==29012== 
==29012== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29012== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 17)
```

**Good: Using `reset()`**

```
#include <memory>

namespace
{
    template<typename T, typename ...Args>
    std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&& ...args)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = make_unique<int>(5);
    ptr.reset(); // HERE
}
```

Valgrind Output

```
==29045== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29045==     in use at exit: 35,356 bytes in 441 blocks
==29045==   total heap usage: 508 allocs, 67 frees, 41,216 bytes allocated
==29045== 
==29045== LEAK SUMMARY:
==29045==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29045==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29045==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29045==    still reachable: 192 bytes in 6 blocks
==29045==         suppressed: 35,164 bytes in 435 blocks
==29045== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==29045== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==29045== 
==29045== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29045== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 17 from 17)
```

The same output as above (the Good) is received by simply removing the second line in `main()` entirely.

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = make_unique<int>(5);
}
```

And likewise with this:

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = make_unique<int>(5);
    std::unique_ptr<int> other(ptr.release());
}
```

Best of luck.