# Cannot seem to assign a unique_ptr to a struct

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a unique_ptr member on a class that points to a struct.

```
class ExampleClass {
    std::unique_ptr<StateStruct> _character_state;
}
```

I don't understand how to acquire the memory for the struct and set the unique_ptr.

In my constructor I have:

```
ExampleClass::ExampleClass {
    std::unique_ptr<StateStruct> _character_state(static_cast<StateStruct*>(malloc(sizeof(StateStruct))));
    _character_state->state_member_int_value = 4 // _character_state is empty
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `malloc()` rather using `new`  seriously??

Comment: Your struct is probably not initialized correctly because of this `malloc` nonsense you do. You also most likely do not even need a pointer here.

Comment: I particularly like the juxtaposition of malloc() with a C++ style cast.

Comment: Err.. no one noticed that he is creating a *local* `_character_state` that  hides the member `_character_state`? This has noting to do with  the `malloc`.

Comment: Haha... yes I am still learning.... In my defense, this represented a moment of extreme desperation. I am working with a code base that is over 20 years old. @sbabbi, can you explain what you mean by creating a local state that hides the member?

Comment: @adelphospro, in your example ctor you put `typename varname` in the first line without assigning it to the local `ExampleClass::_char_state`. It will be treated as a local var even though it shares the same name.

Comment: @learnvst Ah yes I see. Thank you. It is my first time working with smart pointers and class inheritance in C++ (from a C, then Ruby background. Working with an old c codebase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ExampleClass::ExampleClass() : _character_state( new StateStruct() ) {

}
```

... or if you want to transfer ownership at some point later (you could do this in the constructor also, but does not convey what you are trying to do as clearly)

```
_character_state.reset( new StateStruct() );
```

... or in the interests of completeness, you can assign a fresh `unique_ptr` to your variable if you enjoy typing

```
_character_state = std::unique_ptr<someObject>(new someObject());
```

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer to see `make_unique` instead of `new`.

Comment: @Chris Drew Because the question is tagged C++11 and not C++14 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding Note: I had to look up the details on that first before forming my douchy reply ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well don't use malloc.

```
std::unique_ptr<StateStruct> _character_state(static_cast<StateStruct*>(malloc(sizeof(StateStruct))));
                                                                        ^^^^^^
```

The unique_ptr release the memory with a call to delete (not free).

Also you are creating a local variable inside the constructor (not initializing the member variable). Prefer to initialize member variables inside the initializer list not in the body of the constructor.

```
ExampleClass::ExampleClass {
    _character_state(new StateStruct)
{
    // Should you not move this to the constructor
    // if StateStruct
    _character_state->state_member_int_value = 4
}
```

Comment: To be frankly you can make it call `free()` but I do not see any reason to use malloc/free

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

First of all your syntax is wrong, you are missing brackets. Second, inside your constructor you are creating local variable `_character_state` which would hide member variable and leave it uninitialized. So proper syntax is:

```
ExampleClass::ExampleClass() :
    _character_state( std::make_unique<StateStruct>() )
{
    _character_state->state_member_int_value = 4 // _character_state is empty
}
```

If you, for watever reason, have to create `StateStruct` with `malloc()`, you would need to supply custom deleter, that calls `free()`.

If you do not really need `malloc()` you probably should initialize `state_member_int_value` inside `StateStruct` own constructor.