# Vector of QThreads

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I am trying to multithread my image recording application in order to optimize performances and prevent the GUI from freezing.
I tried to create a vector of CaptureThread (my class which extends QThread) but it does not compile...

here is my code:

```
vector<CaptureThread> v_ct_Threads(i_SelectedCameras);

for(int i = 0; i < i_SelectedCameras; i++) {
    v_ct_Threads[i] = CaptureThread(i, qsb_Duration->value());
    v_ct_Threads[i].start();
}

for(int i = 0; i < i_SelectedCameras; i++) {
    v_ct_Threads[i].wait();
}
```

And the error:

```
use of deleted function ‘CaptureThread& CaptureThread::operator=(CaptureThread&&)’
v_ct_Threads[i] = CaptureThread(i, qsb_Duration->value());
```

I guess it's a stupid mistake but I am a beginner in C++ and Qt...

Comment: you cant copy threads. Maybe `emplace_back` can help

Comment: You may just want a QThreadPool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy constructor of the CaptureThread is deleted, probably because the QThread cannot be copied.

You couldput pointers of your CaptureThreads into the vector of threads.

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<CaptureThread>> v_ct_Threads(i_SelectedCameras);

for(int i = 0; i < i_SelectedCameras; i++) {
    v_ct_Threads[i] = std::make_unique<CaptureThread>(i, qsb_Duration->value());
    v_ct_Threads[i]->start();
}

for(int i = 0; i < i_SelectedCameras; i++) {
    v_ct_Threads[i]->wait();
}
```

Comment: I updated to C++ 14 and your solution seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: @BlackSilver-55 `std::make_unique` is part of c++14. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038357/make-unique-and-perfect-forwarding for more information about it, how to work around it's absence in c++11 and how to implement your own version.

Comment: In C++11 you can use: `v_ct_Threads[i] = std::unique_ptr<CaptureThread>(new CaptureThread(i, qsb_Duration->value()));`